# How to count total lines changed in a year grouped by specific author in a Git repository?

Tags: git

I have found many scripts but not according to date. I need preapre some of yearly asuming for my team and I need some real number? I would like to know How many line were pushed in 2019 for all and the same grouped by user. Could you point me right direction to resolve it?

Comment: Here's a quick way to count insertions and deletions for a single user: `git log --author=phil --format= --numstat first-sha-of-year~.. | awk '{ ins += $1; del += $2 } END { print ins " " del }'`

Comment: I, sometime, use gitstat for personal stats :
https://github.com/hoxu/gitstats
Not perfect, but can do the job for your need

Comment: With the git command: diff --stat <sha1> <sha2> you find the files and the amount of changes between two commits. You can do this for the first and last commit of 2019 if you wish. You can do this with two proximate o continuous commit to see how it works.